# Where can I find a tutorial for using OpenLayers in an Azure WebApp?

Tags: node.js, express, azure-web-app-service, openlayers

I can get the functionality I need to work quite well when hosting the app with VS Code and Vite, but when I publish to my Azure WebApp I am unable to see the site.   The build and deployment appear successful, with no errors in the logs.    This is all I see in my browser.

":( Application Error
If you are the application administrator, you can access the diagnostic resources."

I tried following the Microsoft overviews on Azure WebApp setup with Node, but they use ExpressJS which isn't in the OpenLayers examples.   When I set up ExpressJS in my app, I get tons of errors relating to not being able to find the javascript files.    If I add a relative path and ".js" to each of the import statements, I can slowly work through them, but I have yet to reach the end.   There is a lot of javascript in OpenLayers.   My ExpressJS app works fine on Azure until I try to incorporate the OpenLayers code.

Comment: can you share your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I created a simple OpenLayers application with Node.js and successfully deployed it to Azure App Service.

I used the code from this [document](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/simple.html).

**main.js** :

```js
import Map from 'ol/Map.js';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM.js';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile.js';
import View from 'ol/View.js';
const map = new Map({
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM(),
    }),
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2,
  }),
});
```

**index.html** :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>WebGIS</title>
    <style>
        .map {
          width: 100%;
          height:600px;
        }
      </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script src="main.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**package.json** :

```json
{
  "name": "openlayout",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
    "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "vite",
    "build": "vite build"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ol": "^8.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "vite": "^3.2.8"
  }
}
```

For deployment purposes, I run the following command: `npm run build`. This generates a dist folder.

I successfully published the web app through Visual Studio Code to Azure App Service.

[image]

I added the following command to the startup command in the configuration section of the Azure web app.

`pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/dist --no-daemon --spa`.

[image]

**Output** :
[image]

Comment: Thank you!   I was missing the startup command.     How did you know what to put in there?

I replaced my code with that from the OpenLayers example, so I'm going to start putting my code back in, and I'll see if it still works.